# Knitting Rmarkdown to have AIC round to one's place while rounding regression coefficients and SE to tenth's place

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

I use the following function in the setup of Rmarkdown to make it so that in knitting everything rounds to two decimal places, but how can I alter the code to create a conditional such that for AIC (x>1000, for instance) it will round to the one's place?

Thanks!

Minimal reproducible example using mtcars data set. Looking at the effect of car weight on mpg with a random factor of cylinder. Make sure to knit everything below in Rmarkdown...if you just use the code in R, it will round the AIC.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default

---
```{r echo = FALSE, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(scientific=FALSE)

scientific=FALSE
# knitr::clean_cache()
options(digits=3)

library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

inline_hook <- function (x) {
  if (is.numeric(x)) {
    # ifelse does a vectorized comparison
    # If integer, print without decimal; otherwise print two places
    res <- ifelse(x == round(x),
      sprintf("%d", x),
      sprintf("%.3f", x)
    )
    paste(res, collapse = ", ")
  }
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = inline_hook)

mpg <- lmer(mpg~wt + (1|cyl), mtcars, na.action = 'na.exclude', control = lmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE), REML = FALSE)
AIC(logLik(mpg))
coef(summary(mpg))[2]
```

AIC = `r AIC(logLik(mpg))`
Effect size = `r coef(summary(mpg))[2]`
````

Comment: Would you please provide a minimal example of how you compute the AIC and how you intent to print it?

Comment: Sorry, the fix seemed identifiable without data, but the above with mtcars should give an idea of what's going on. Thanks, CL.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I realized that what I had in mind doesn't work. My plan was to inspect the class of the object that is (implicitly) printed in the inline R code and then ... nevermind: The inline hook only sees the output to be printed (as character data). Therefore: Sorry, I have no useful idea (except for manually `sprintf`ing as needed).

Comment: Shoot--well, I guess there are worse things then doing it manually. Thanks